# shape cannot be sharded 8 ways along dimension 0

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-tpu, tpu

Im trying to run a custom estimator on Compute engine and google cloud TPU however I get an error:

```
ValueError: shape [2] cannot be sharded 8 ways along dimension 0
```

I have no idea what causes or how to fix it - any idea?

Andy P.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a two valued vector. All dimensions for the TPU ideally would be divisible by 8. If you're just playing around, I suggest just making an 8 long vector.

More info: https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tpus#dimensions